# fread/fwrite in C

Tags: c, file, io, fwrite, fread

Let's say I have these parameters:

```
bool array_serialize(const void *src_data,
                const char *dst_file,
                const size_t elem_size,
                const size_t elem_count);
```

Assume that `src_data` is the array I'd like to write into `dst_file`.

I can't quite figure out how to use `fwrite`. I know that `fwrite` requires four parameters:

- `ptr` − This is the pointer to the array of elements to be written.
- `size` − This is the size in bytes of each element to be written.
- `nmemb` − This is the number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
- `stream` − This is the pointer to a `FILE` object that specifies an output stream.

But the problem I run into is that `*dst_file` is of `const char` type. How can I convert this into the appropriate type to be able to use `fwrite`?
I've tried doing

```
fwrite(src_data, elem_size, elem_count, dst_file);
```

but obviously this is incorrect.

Similar question for `fread` as well.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages!

Comment: You need first `fopen` the file...

Comment: And stack overflow is no tutoring site. Please read the man pages of the functions or consult a C book - they are explained in likely every C book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First read the ref *twice*: [fwrite()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) and [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/).

The last parameter should be a file ponter, so do it like this:

```
fp = fopen(dst_file, "w+");
if(fp != NULL) {
    fwrite(src_data, elem_size, elem_count, fp);
    rewind(fp);
    fread(result_data, elem_size, elem_count, fp);
}
```

Take a look on [more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180006/how-to-use-fread-and-fwrite-functions-to-read-and-write-binary-files).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I feel like an idiot now. I'll take more time researching before posting next time. I'll accept when I am allowed.

Comment: @MikeHenke learn from the mistake, feel no shame. ;) If I could I would vote for you, but I am on a limit.

Answer (score 0):

const char is effectively a byte type, you can cast it to any type you want to.
If you have a binary file stored with a known pattern (you better) you read the type by the member size into your target struct.

So for instance if you have a struct with two variables

```
struct foo {
  int f1;
  int f2;
};
```

And you know that the entire file is made up of these, then you can fread the values from the file like this

```
fread(&target, sizeof(foo), num_elems, fp)
```

You can rinse and repeat this based on the file you are reading or writing.

Additionally you can structure the file to have headers which tell you what type of data is stored, and how many of them there are, which allows you to have variable structures in a single file.

Comment: Please note it has been about 6 months since I wrote any C, so there may be errors in my code

Comment: Sorry – no real errors in your code (although reading and writing `struct`s may have padding issues and thus needs a note on that), but it does not answer OP's question regarding the correct parameter type for `dst_file`.

Comment: The correct parameter type is any pointer to a datatype.
Good point on the padding, that would be where my getting out of c coding shows.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question